# .htaccess after multiple get variable css, images, etc. won't load

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a rewriting rule in my .htaccess and when I use only one get variable everything works great. When I use 2 or 3 get variables only the html is loaded and the css and images etc not.

How can I fix this problem? I have tried base tag but still didn't(maybe doing it wrong)

Here is my code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)?$ car-details.php?model=$1&titel=$2&car_id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Here is my code in car-details.php :

```
if (isset($_GET['model'],$_GET['titel'],$_GET['car_id']) === true ) { 
$model=     trim ($_GET['model']); 
$titel =   trim($_GET['titel']); 
$car_id =  trim($_GET['car_id']);
```

Comment: use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by putting this code in HTML head section:

```
<base href="http://www.mydomain.com/">
```